# Could not find or load main class mvn when launching jenkins job

Tags: maven, jenkins

I think i have setted everthing that is needed to run a jenkins job with Maven, but i keep getting an error everytime i run my job.
Im using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Jenkins 1.642.

The complete error:

```
Parsing POMs
[RaceCom] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/bin/java mvn --batch-mode release:update-versions -DdevelopmentVersion=1.2.0-SNAPSHOT -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-agent-1.5.jar:/home/damian/Documents/apache-maven-3.3.9/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/home/damian/Documents/apache-maven-3.3.9/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main /home/damian/Documents/apache-maven-3.3.9/ /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.53.3.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-interceptor-1.5.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar 50845
Error: Could not find or load main class mvn
ERROR: Failed to launch Maven. Exit code = 1
```

Java Home environment variable and version check:

```
damian@damian-server:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
damian@damian-server:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

Maven Home environment variable and version check:

```
damian@damian-server:~$ echo $M2_HOME
/home/damian/Documents/apache-maven-3.3.9
damian@damian-server:~$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T13:41:47-03:00)
Maven home: /home/damian/Documents/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_77, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-35-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Jenkins config, MAVEN_HOME: /home/damian/Documents/apache-maven-3.3.9/

If i run Maven in the terminal works perfectly.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Configure Maven-jar-plugin in pom.xml to set the main class of the project during build phase.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>your.main.Class</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```